# How to disable indexing for a big Swift project?

Tags: xcode, indexing, swift

I have a big Swift project. It's about 40 ViewControllers, 2 storyboards and some frameworks. When I make some changes XCode begins indexing all the project and it takes a very long time!

How can I disable indexing and compiling some unnecessary Swift files?

Comment: There are some big improvements for Swift builds in Swift 1.2 that'll come with XCode 6.3